# Create a Lookup filter on Settlement

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am not very familiar how is all the settlement works behind the code. However I have notice that when we do settlement, only selected vendor and posted journal will be display. Hence I would like to make use of this properties to customized so that when user is using a certain journal name to create the journal (eg: 01-GJ-MY), the list of settlement display on the open transaction editing will only display voucher that belongs to specific Journal (eg: 01-INV-MY).

[Specific Journal Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCTPl.png) Select specific Journal Name from General Journal

[Select Mark settlement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lOFj.png)Select Mark settlement From the General Journal

[Display settlement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npr5Z.png)Only Voucher that belongs to Journal with name 01-INV-MY will display on the settlement list

However the VendOpenTrans Form is quite complex that I am not sure which is the method I should modify to perform this customization.Besides that I'm afraid that any customization will affect other Journal from performing settlement. Is there any idea what is the method I should overwrite from? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Axapta are you using?

Comment: the Axapta is AX 2009

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?